# windows program, top bar menu, add item to specific program

Tags: windows-7, windows

A windows program has the windows bar on top, the program icon on the left, the 3 buttons on the right.

You can right click on this bar or the icon to get a menu with the items "Restore, Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize, Close". (What is the name of this specific menu?)

Where are the menu items of a specific programs defined?

Is it possible to add an item to the menu of a specific program?

I would like to add an item to one specific program only, this item then should start a script.
Specifically: A program does not have the option to print the windows contents. I would like to start a script through this menu to print the windows contents. The Windows 7 OS where this program runs on is very restricted, no snipping tool is allowed, no paint, no task bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "system menu" (aka "window menu"). The contents are standard and provided by Windows, though programs can modify a given window's menu by using the [GetSystemMenu()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647985(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

(It still appears to be possible to modify windows belonging to another program, such as in [this AHK example](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/17759-window-system-menu-manipulator-library-v20/).)

However, menu items don't directly specify "scripts to run" – they only have numeric action IDs, and the program itself must be written to recognize the ID you've added. So if this is an entirely new action (not something that already exists in the program's other menus), you'll need to patch the program itself, or find some ways to inject code into it.

I wouldn't be surprised if there already were tools for this (perhaps under "desktop customization"), but I don't know any offhand.